# What is the use of view/change user data if that script is not run when we stop and then start the EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

AWS console has the option to view/change user data where we can change the data when the instance is stopped. But what i am unable to understand is why is this option to edit provided if the script is not run when we stop and restart the instance.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html

Answer (score 1):

Because cloud-init is just one use for user data (and it came into existence *after* EC2).

Consider instead a pre-built AMI that is already configured to run a service. That service needs to be configured in some way, and user data is a great way to do that (especially prior to the introduction of AWS Systems Manager). For example, you could store a list of variable settings in user data, then have the service read those into its environment.

Using configuration in that way, it's very nice to be able to change user data and restart the service to pick up changes.

Comment: Yes. User Data existing before its was used to run a startup script. However, please note that User Data cannot be changed on a _running_ instance. It needs to stop first.

Comment: Hmm, I swear that I've changed user data on a running instance, but just tried it and it does require a stop/start cycle. Edited.